# minimum distance between a point and a compact set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $Y$ be a compact subset of $X$. Show that if $x \notin Y$, then

$$ d(x,Y) = \inf_{y \in Y} \{d(x,y)\} >0$$

The statement seems quite simple to imagine but I do not know how to prove it. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Suppose $\inf_{y\in Y}d(x,y)=0$. Let $(y_n)\in Y^{\mathbb N}$ s.t. $$\lim_{n\to \infty }d(x,y_n)=0.$$

Use compactness of $Y$ (or rather the fact that $Y$ is closed) to prove that $x\in Y$, what will be a contradiction.

---

**An other proof**

Since $Y^c$ is open, there is $\delta >0$ s.t. $B_d(x,\delta )\subset Y^c$, where $B(x,\delta )$ denotes the ball centered at $x$ and of radius $\delta $). Therefore $d(x,Y)\geq \delta >0$.

Comment: Where exactly would we need the compactness? Wouldn't it suffice that $Y$ is closed, hence $x=\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n \in Y$? I suppose you want to use compactness to get a convergent subsequence, but isn't $y_n$ itself already convergent? Sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: @GhostAmarth: Indeed, $Y$ being closed is enough, and you are right, $(y_n)$ is already convergent.

Comment: I get it! So by closedness, $Y$ must contain its limit points, which is, in this case, $x$. Right? I don't know why I haven't thought of that. Thanks!

Comment: @Morcus: yes exactly.

Comment: If $Y$ is assumed to only be closed, the statement will not hold because $Y$ may not be complete. So compactness is needed, Right?

Comment: @Morcus: completeness is not needed here, and as we can see in the hint I gave you, only closeness is needed.

Answer (score 2):

The function $y \to d(x,y)$ is continuous on $Y$, only assumes values in $(0,+\infty)$, and so by compactness has a minimal value $m_0 >0$. Then $d(x,Y)=m_0>0$.

Or assume $d(x,Y)=0$ so that for each $n \in \Bbb N^+$ we have some $y_n \in Y$ such that $d(x,y_n) < \frac1n$.

As $Y$ is compact we have some subsequence $(y_{n_k})_k$ and some $y_0 \in Y$ such that $y_{n_k} \to y_0$ as $k\to \infty$.

But then $d(x,y_0) \le d(x,y_{n_k}) + d(y_{n_k}, y_0) < \frac{1}{n_k} + d(y_{n_k}, y_0) \to 0 (k \to \infty)$, so that $d(x,y_0)= 0$ and this would implies $x=y_0$ contradiction as $x \notin Y$. So $d(x,Y) >0$.

Comment: Note that it follows that $Y$ is closed, which is in fact enough.

Comment: I'm ot so sure in what your answer is different than mine. By the way, if $d(x,y_n)<\frac{1}{n}$ directly gives that $y_n\to x$, and thus $x\in Y$. No need to pass by a convergence subsequence...

Comment: @Surb but you use that $Y$ is closed, which is not given. I use compactness directly. This fact eventually *proves* that a compact subset of a metric space is closed, but the OP might not have known that.